# create web service for android app using wordpress website

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, api, web-services

I have to create Web services for android app using WordPress Database. where user can login and register using android app. that record will be saved in WordPress database. display All the  posts of wordpress site in android app using wordpress database table. user can Create and Update  User Profile ,Login , Register ,Posts etc.

I want to Know any WordPress API or web services Plugin is there  which can interact with WordPress Tables. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress [JSON API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) may be of use to you, which lets you access the Wordpress tables via a RESTful API. You can also add your own custom controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you could use the [WordPress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) via xmlrpc.

Keep in mind xmlprc is often a target for attackers, so turning it on (if it's not on/locked down already) may weaken your site's security.

Answer (score 0):

The [WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) will soon be part of WordPress core and available to developers without the need for plugins. You can find [the documentation here](http://v2.wp-api.org/) and follow its progress on [the core development blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/json-api/).